# AttributeError: form instance has no attribute 'buttonI' in pygtk

Tags: python, python-2.7, gtk, pygtk, attributeerror

I'm trying to write a script that will do check-box invisible when i click on main check-box.

This is code which i have written for that

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk, cairo, gio, pango, pangocairo, atk, gobject

class form:
    def typeentry(self, widget, data):
        if data=="num" and widget.get_active()==True:
            self.buttonI.set_visible(True)
            self.buttonS.set_visible(True)
            self.buttonF.set_visible(True)
            self.buttonL.set_visible(True)
        if data=="num" and widget.get_active()==False:
            self.buttonI.set_visible(False)
            self.buttonS.set_visible(False)
            self.buttonF.set_visible(False)
            self.buttonL.set_visible(False)
    def __init__(self):
        self.win = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        self.win.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
        self.win.set_size_request(530, 340)
        self.win.set_resizable(False)

        evbox = gtk.VBox(False, 0)            
        frame = gtk.AspectFrame("Select", 1.0, 1.0,3, False)
        frame.set_border_width(10)
        vbox = gtk.VBox(False, 5)
        vbox.set_border_width(5)
        frame.add(vbox)
        vbox.set_uposition(90,165)
        button = gtk.CheckButton("Number")
        button.connect("toggled", self.typeentry, "num")
        vbox.pack_start(button, False, False, 2)
        button.set_active(True)

        button = gtk.CheckButton("String")
        vbox.pack_start(button, False, False, 0)
        button.set_active(True)

        self.buttonI = gtk.CheckButton("int")
        self.buttonI.connect("toggled", self.typeentry, "int")
        vbox.pack_start(self.buttonI, False, False, 0)
        self.buttonI.set_active(True)
        self.buttonI.set_uposition(300,155)

        self.buttonF = gtk.CheckButton("float")
        self.buttonF.connect("toggled", self.typeentry, "float")
        vbox.pack_start(self.buttonF, False, False, 0)
        self.buttonF.set_active(True)
        self.buttonF.set_uposition(300,170)

        self.buttonL = gtk.CheckButton("long")
        self.buttonL.connect("toggled", self.typeentry, "long")
        vbox.pack_start(self.buttonL, False, False, 0)
        self.buttonL.set_active(True)
        self.buttonL.set_uposition(300,185)

        self.buttonS = gtk.CheckButton("short")
        self.buttonS.connect("toggled", self.typeentry, "short")
        vbox.pack_start(self.buttonS, False, False, 0)
        self.buttonS.set_active(True)
        self.buttonS.set_uposition(300,200)

        evbox.add(frame)
        self.win.add(evbox)

        hbox = gtk.HBox(False, 0)
        evbox.pack_start(hbox, False, True, 5)
        hbox.set_uposition(0,295)

        button = gtk.Button("Previous")
        button.connect("clicked", lambda w: gtk.main_quit())
        button.set_size_request(90,35)
        hbox.pack_start(button, False, False,10)

        dbox = gtk.HBox(False, 0)
        button = gtk.Button("Next")
        button.connect("clicked", lambda w: gtk.main_quit())
        button.set_size_request(90,35)
        dbox.pack_end(button, True, True, 5)

        button = gtk.Button("Exit")
        button.set_size_request(90,35)
        dbox.pack_end(button, True, True,5)

        hbox.pack_end(dbox, False,True, 5)

        self.win.show_all()


    def main(self):
        gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    first = form()
    first.main()
```

the code is running fine but at the time of running this code. it is showing below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\Eclipse Project\Sample\test.py", line 12, in typeentry
    self.buttonI.set_visible(True)
AttributeError: form instance has no attribute 'buttonI'
```

I am not understanding what is happening and what i do. please somebody help me for it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are calling `typeentry` function with another checkbox button which you have defined latter on that's why it is showing error. so first you have to define all the checkbox button then you can call the function.

just see the updated code, it is running fine.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk, cairo, gio, pango, pangocairo, atk, gobject

class form:
    def typeentry(self, widget, data):
        print "hi"
        if data=="num" and widget.get_active()==True:
            self.buttonS.set_visible(True)
            self.buttonI.set_visible(True)
            self.buttonF.set_visible(True)
            self.buttonL.set_visible(True)
        if data=="num" and widget.get_active()==False:
            self.buttonI.set_visible(False)
            self.buttonS.set_visible(False)
            self.buttonF.set_visible(False)
            self.buttonL.set_visible(False)
    def __init__(self):
        self.win = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        self.win.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
        self.win.set_size_request(530, 340)
        self.win.set_resizable(False)

        evbox = gtk.VBox(False, 0)            
        frame = gtk.AspectFrame("Select", 1.0, 1.0,3, False)
        frame.set_border_width(10)
        vbox = gtk.VBox(False, 5)
        vbox.set_border_width(5)
        frame.add(vbox)
        vbox.set_uposition(90,165)
        button1 = gtk.CheckButton("Number")
        vbox.pack_start(button1, False, False, 2)
        button1.set_active(True)

        button2 = gtk.CheckButton("String")
        vbox.pack_start(button2, False, False, 0)
        button2.set_active(True)

        self.buttonI = gtk.CheckButton("int")

        vbox.pack_start(self.buttonI, False, False, 0)
        self.buttonI.set_active(True)
        self.buttonI.set_uposition(300,155)

        self.buttonF = gtk.CheckButton("float")

        vbox.pack_start(self.buttonF, False, False, 0)
        self.buttonF.set_active(True)
        self.buttonF.set_uposition(300,170)

        self.buttonL = gtk.CheckButton("long")

        vbox.pack_start(self.buttonL, False, False, 0)
        self.buttonL.set_active(True)
        self.buttonL.set_uposition(300,185)

        self.buttonS = gtk.CheckButton("short")
        vbox.pack_start(self.buttonS, False, False, 0)
        self.buttonS.set_active(True)
        self.buttonS.set_uposition(300,200)

        button1.connect("clicked", self.typeentry, "num")
        self.buttonI.connect("clicked", self.typeentry, "int")
        self.buttonF.connect("clicked", self.typeentry, "float")
        self.buttonL.connect("clicked", self.typeentry, "long")
        self.buttonS.connect("clicked", self.typeentry, "short")
        evbox.add(frame)
        self.win.add(evbox)

        hbox = gtk.HBox(False, 0)
        evbox.pack_start(hbox, False, True, 5)
        hbox.set_uposition(0,295)

        button = gtk.Button("Previous")
        button.connect("clicked", lambda w: gtk.main_quit())
        button.set_size_request(90,35)
        hbox.pack_start(button, False, False,10)

        dbox = gtk.HBox(False, 0)
        button = gtk.Button("Next")
        button.connect("clicked", lambda w: gtk.main_quit())
        button.set_size_request(90,35)
        dbox.pack_end(button, True, True, 5)

        button = gtk.Button("Exit")
        button.set_size_request(90,35)
        dbox.pack_end(button, True, True,5)

        hbox.pack_end(dbox, False,True, 5)

        self.win.show_all()


    def main(self):
        gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    first = form()
    first.main()
```

Answer (score 3):

`self.typeentry()` gets called when you set "Number" and String" checkbutton active properties. This is before the other buttons even exist.

Answer (score 2):

```
 button = gtk.CheckButton("Number")
 button.connect("toggled", self.typeentry, "num")
 vbox.pack_start(button, False, False, 2)
 button.set_active(True)
```

The call to `button.set_active` triggers the `toogled` event and thus `self.typeentry` is called where you try to access a member of `self.buttonI` and others. At this point however `self.buttonI` and the other buttons haven't been defined yet.

Instead add the event handler later (you don't need it while initializing):

```
 button = gtk.CheckButton("Number")
 vbox.pack_start(button, False, False, 2)
 button.set_active(True)
 button.connect("toggled", self.typeentry, "num")
```

Comment: Thanks nabla for giving solution